# R Error in if-nest and/or for-loop? Unexpected '}' in "}"

Tags: r, syntax

I'm trying to work with a table called 'data' in **R**.

My code is roughly like this:

```
for (i in nrow(data):1) {
  data$meanApproval[i] = mean(data[max(1,i-11):i,5])

  if(data$Poll = data[duplicated(data$Poll),]) {
    data = data[!duplicated(data$Poll),]
  }
}
```

It throws the error as in the title:

> "Unexpected '}' in "}""

The syntax before I added this code gave no complaint, so I'm sure it's the section I've posted.

I know this may be considered a duplicate question, but I've studied all the other answers, and none of them help me with this issue. I can't find any missing bracket matches, and none of these are the result of a unicode misread.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you want `data$Poll = data[duplicated(data$Poll),]` and not `data$Poll == ata[duplicated(data$Poll),]` (== instead of =)?

Comment: Yes, that seems to have done the trick. That leaves me with new challenges, but not ones related the question. Curse my tunnel vision, and thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message was misleading from the actual error in the code.

```
if(data$Poll = data[duplicated(data$Poll),]) {
...
}
```

should have read `==` for the `if` check

```
if(data$Poll == data[duplicated(data$Poll),]) {
...
}
```